# How to test slide-box in protractor

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e

I have a slide-box described in one of my protractor tests; I can find the box and can get properties (i.e. 'how many') but how do I cycle through the boxes so I can test verify the display, e.g.

```
profilepage.slides.next()
expect(profilepage.slide.slideTitle  = 'Credentials'
profilepage.slides.next()
expect(profilepage.slide.slideTitle = "Info"
etc.
```

Controller:

```
.controller('ProfileCtrl', function ($scope, ProfileService) {

    $scope.data = {
        numViewableSlides: 0,
        slideIndex: 0,
        initialInstruction: true,
        secondInstruction: false, slides: [
            {
                'template': 'templates/slidebox/credentials.html',
                'viewable': true
            },

            {
                'template': 'templates/slidebox/contactinfo.html',
                'viewable': true
            },
            {
                'template': 'templates/slidebox/employeeinfo.html',
                'viewable': true
            },
            {
                'template': 'templates/slidebox/assignmentinfo.html',
                'viewable': true
            }
        ]
    }
    . . .
```

Template:

```
    <ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideChanged(index)" show-pager="true">

        <ion-slide ng-repeat="slide in data.slides | filter:{viewable : true}">
            <div ng-include src="slide.template"></div>
        </ion-slide>

    </ion-slide-box>
```

Page Object:

```
profilepage.prototype = Object.create({}, {
backButton: {
    get: function () {
        return element(by.css('ion-ios7-arrow-back'));
    }
},
slides: {
    get: function () {
        return element.all(by.repeater('slide in data.slides'));
    }
},
slideTitle: {
    get: function (id) {
        element.all(by.repeater('slide in data.slides')).then(function (slidelist) {
            var titleElement = slidelist[id].element(by.css('#slideName'));
            return titleElement.getText();
        });
    }
},
. . .
```

Spec:

```
describe('Profile', function () {

var ppage = new profilepage();

beforeEach(function () {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
});

it('should have correct lastname and have four slides on profile page', function () {
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('http://localhost:8100/#/profile');
    expect(ppage.lastname).toBe('Smith,');
    expect(ppage.slides.count()).toEqual(4);
    browser.sleep(1000);
});

it('should slide all the pages', function(){
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('http://localhost:8100/#/profile');
    // SLIDE EACH PAGE ABOUT HERE  <------------
    browser.sleep(1000);
})
```

Comment: I'm not a programmer, but have worked with Protractor a bit. 

could you explain what the users action is to "slide" to the next "slide"? Is this an example of what you are making/testing? http://codepen.io/keithjgrant/pen/vqnaA

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use ionic's [$ionicSlideBoxDelegate](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicSlideBoxDelegate/) from within the spec file. For that we'll need to make it accessible globally:

```
var addProtractorSlideBox, nextSlide;

addProtractorSlideBox = function() {
  return browser.addMockModule("services", function() {
    return angular.module("services").run(function($ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {
      return window._$ionicSlideBoxDelegate = $ionicSlideBoxDelegate;
    });
  });
};

nextSlide = function() {
  return browser.executeScript('_$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.next()');
};

...

beforeEach(function() {
  ...
  addProtractorSlideBox();
  ...
});

it('...', function() {
  ...
  nextSlide();
  ...
})
```

This pattern is very useful for other ionic/angular services.

Comment: it looks fine, except it missing module("services",[]) empty brackets for a new module :)